# Auto-Complete Field Aligned Top Left

Tags: configuration, autocomplete, leaflet

**NOTE:** *This is the intrinsic (built-in) autocomplete that comes with Firefox. I remember the fix having something to with a setting in Firefox's `about:config` page if that helps.*

I had a fix for this involving changing a configuration setting but now I forget how to do it. This is it:

[image: Problem]

What is it? It's a simple `about:config` fix, perhaps something to do with acceleration of some kind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the picture, I would assume that the container element of the autocomplete field needs to be set to position:relative. That is the best guess I can give without code.

Comment: I specified it is an `about:config` issue. Nothing CSS to do with here.

Answer (score 0):

*Originally the question was tagged [css](/questions/tagged/css) and did not mention that autocomplete is the built-in one. Keeping answer for the JavaScript + CSS (e.g. jQuery UI autocomplete) case for future visitors.*

## Built-in autocomplete

Page contents (even CSS and JavaScript) do not influence the built-in autocomplete functionality, AFAIK. Page author can use just the [autocomplete attribute in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fe-autocomplete) and the [`requestAutocomplete`](http://www.chromium.org/developers/using-requestautocomplete) API in Chromium.

The only thing that could influence the built-in autocomplete is browser settings. Bad suggestions list position is definitely a browser bug. You are just looking for a work-around, for a configuration that does not trigger the bug. Firefox configuration is accessible in `about:config`, so you can be right that you need to change something there.

The only thing that came to my mind regarding UI display is hardware acceleration, which tends to cause trouble. That can be tweaked (and turned off) via `about:config`. Search for *layers*. You said that it does not solve your problem; I’m stucked as I have no other idea.

## JavaScript autocomplete

The issue is probably caused by absolute positioning and bad choice of the coordinate system in this case. For more info see [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#containing-block) and [absolute positioning](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolute-positioning) in the spec.

Try changing the `position` property of the enclosing box to `relative`.

```
#mailinput {
    position: relative;
}
#mailinput #mail_autocomplete {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.5em;
}
```